# DomCrawler search inside javascript block

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping

I am using Symfony2 DomCrawler to serch for specific nodes via scrapping

But now I want a value from javascript CDATA section which is in the form as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 var objj = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"};
//]]>
</script>
```

Now my question is it possible to get the value of specific key from above declared var objj using the DomCrawler . If not then plz suggest some other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Use DomCrawler to get node's content (script), then you can use preg_match to extract the value you want.